# How to make the background of rendered depth image black?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, depth-of-field

So I am trying to render color and depth image at the same time. The color image for the scene is:

[image]

As you can see, the background of this image is purely black. I want to have black background as well for the depth image. However, I could only get this:

[image]

My node editor looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to do so?

Any suggestions are appreciated!